# Cant update Android SDK tools from 20 to 21

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to update my `Android SDK tools` from 20 to 21. But I am unable to see version 21 on SDK manager. I am using `Linux 12.04` and `eclipse 3.X.` 
Please find the attached Image [image]

Please Suggest me.

Comment: Have you try to update your ADT Eclipse plugin first?

Comment: @Evos, When I tried to re-install ADT I am getting an error "Android DDMS" will be ignored because it is already installed.

Comment: "Android DDMS" will be ignored because it is already installed. "Android Development Tools" will be ignored because it is already installed.

Comment: I have no idea why it doesn't update your DDMS, i think best solution for you will be fullt reinstall Eclipse and/or Android SDK. It will  quicker that searching for reasons of this problems. GL!

Answer (score 9):

Try to reload the packages. it will solve the issue .

http://tools.android.com/knownissues

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all.

Some how I tried to do this. I downloaded `another version of eclipse(latest indigo)` and installed `ADT plug-in` in it and I could easily update `SDK`

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the ADT plugin in Eclipse first, only then the option will be visible.

In other words,go to Help>Check for updates in Eclipse, once that is done, the update for android will be available to you.

Comment: When I do  Help>Check for updates, There will be a big Issue. It will be unable to see Android Development Manager on Eclipse

Comment: Do you see Android Development Tools there?

Comment: If I do Help>Check for updates, I will be uable to see Android Development Tools there

Comment: okay, this is probably going to sound dumb but try restarying eclpise and then updating it, then see if you get the options. btw what options do u see there?

Comment: No Luck With that restarting of eclipse

Comment: When I click Check for Update, a progress bar appears and after processing It shows the available updates but it doesn't contain ADT update

Answer (score 0):

I Have done this in Windows some time before, so I don´t know if it works with Linux. I updated first with Android SDK Manager, then after this was done, I updated my Android at eclipse, this worked for me. Both Updates where done as Administrator.